# VirtualBox running Ubuntu distro - troubleshooting

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine.  It looked like everything was well and dandy, until this screen showed up after the boot-up:

[image: error]

I'm not sure what to fix.  This is my first attempt at using a Linux system, so I'm not very familiar with the details of how things work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is screen of the host system desktop, or a console/VNC screen connected to VM? What is the host system running? What method did you use to install the VM and ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question, but this was a screenshot of the window opened by Virtual box when I booted the virtual machine running ubuntu from my desktop.  I'm running OS X. I used [virtual box's website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to download, and [Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to download the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

As memory serves me, switching TTY's should fix the problem. In your case, your host key is set for left-command, so it would be <kbd>Left-command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Left-command</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. It's a bug.

update: on your Mac, you may have to <kbd>Left-command</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>Left-command</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: This trick got me to a black screen, but unfortunately I didn't find any of the options displayed in [this guide I'm following](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing).  I can't work on this anymore tonight, but thank you for your troubleshooting advice..

Comment: If my commands didn't work, on a Mac, try `left-command+fn+f1` and `left-command+fn+f7`. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this bug more than two years ago: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13615

Oracle thinks it belongs to Ubuntu.

On the Ubuntu side, there are no people (who are enough technically competent) interested in investigating and fixing it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/virtualbox/+bug/1443853

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the VM with 3D Acceleration disabled

OR

Set it to 32mb Video Memory with 3D acceleration turned on.